# Struts 2 Iterate 2D array of objects using <s:iterator>

Tags: java, struts2

I have 2D array in my Action class and I want to iterate it in my jsp.
How do I iterate it using `<s:iterator>` tag of struts.
I'm using Struts 2.3.

I want to design table from it of 3 columns as.

In my Action method I have

```
Object [][] objects;
for(int i=0; i<objects.length; ++i)
    for( int j=0; j<3; ++j)
        sysout(objects[i][j]);
```

I have typed code here...

Comment: use two iterator tags with status attributes and then loop thru.

Comment: @Will how do I access value, in <s:property/> tag

Comment: @Roman C  I had already gone thro' duplicate question, it but it didn't solve my problem...

Comment: `Object [][] objects;
for(int i=0; i<objects.length; ++i)
    for( int j=0; j<3; ++j)
        sysout(objects[i][j]); ` this is my typed code , this is not copy patsed from java file since lack of permission for sharing files, i'm using virt-manager for development